# How to preserve canvas preview after upload? jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I was wondering if someone knows how to preserve canvas preview images (generated by the script on file selection) after the files has been uploaded (clicked start or selected if auto upload is enabled).

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using thumbnailUrl resulted to be easier